# Shiro Guice, where can I set the loginUrl, usernameParam, passwordParam, etc for the FormAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: guice, shiro

In the current setup, I use the shiro.ini.

Moving to Guice, where is the correct place to set these values for the FormAuthenticatorFilter (authc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the parameters via

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.<param>")).to(value)
```

from your `Shiro(Web)Module`.

Comment: I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913745/in-shiro-guice-how-can-i-change-authc-to-a-different-subclass

Answer (score 2):

Shiro Guice's documentation explains [here](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html#Guice-Properties) that you can inject and override several different properties using the following syntax:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.<property>")).to(<propertyValue>);
```

So to answer your question, you can set the "loginUrl" property to "/loginHere" by doing:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.loginUrl")).to("/loginHere");
```