# In Shiro Guice, how can I change authc to a different subclass?

Tags: guice, shiro

Example:

In shiro.ini I have:

```
# Change from FormAuthenticationFilter to VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter
authc=webapp.filters.VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl=/login
authc.successUrl=/oncall
```

How can I perform the above using Shiro Guice? I'm interested in the following line:

```
authc=webapp.filters.VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourShiroSecurityModule extends ShiroWebModule {
    private static final Key<VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter> VERBOSE_AUTH = Key.get(VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public YourShiroSecurityModule(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShiroWeb() {
        [...]
        addFilterChain("<path>", VERBOSE_AUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do the above code, the calls bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.loginUrl").to("/login") does no longer work? As well as all the other variables from the FormAuthenticationFilter (logoutUrl, loginUrl, passwordParam, rememberMeParam, usernameParam).

Comment: Can you post some code snippet? I am having similar problems with the redirectUrl and am still waiting for a response from the Shiro mailing list...